# Android Game starter

Tags: android

I am new and vey much interested  in android stuff. please help on how and where to start the development of game.

Any Prerequisite for that.

Awaiting for reply.

Comment: "How do I get started" questions are off topic for the site.  See the [faq].  There are lots of tutorials out there and technical manuals for whatever platform you're looking to get started on.

Answer (score 2):

You should start by learning java, the language that android is programmed in. Practice it by writing a few non game apps. Then you should look at a game engine, like libGDX or AndEngine. You will also find that a lot of people will recommend that before you write a game on android, you write a few simple ones for your computer, because it is easier to understand and will help you grasp the ropes of game engines.